# Return a value from JQuery Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-widgets

I have created a JQuery Widget to pop-up a dialogue box and to alow values to be accepted from that dialogue box

My Function defining Dialogue close

```
 _ebSaveDialogue: function () {
     //Saving Dialogue
     $('#ebDialogueClose').click(function () {
         var text = $('#ebPlaceholder').val();
         returnText = text;
         $('#ebDialogue_div').dialog("close");
     });
 }
```

How to get the `returnText` value in the html page at the time of closing dialogue?

I tried calling the variable in the html but it return null since the dialogue is nor opened or closed. I want to receive the data in Html at the time of dialogue close

Widget

```
 $.widget('custom.DivPopUp', {

     //Call Constructor
     _create: function () {
         var returnText;
         this._ebDefineDiv();
     },

     _ebDefineDiv: function () {
         if ($("#ebDialogue_div").length == 0) {
             //Bringing Dialogue box
             $("body").append("<div id='ebDialogue_div' title='Expression Builder'></div>");
             var inDialogueDiv = "<div id='ebLeftPanel'></div><div id='ebRightPanel'></div>";
             inDialogueDiv += "<div id='ebSample_div' title='Sample'></div>";

             $('#ebDialogue_div').append(inDialogueDiv);

             this._ebCreateDialoge();
             this._ebSaveDialogue();
         }
     },
     _ebSaveDialogue: function () {
         //Saving Dialogue
         $('#ebDialogueClose').click(function () {
             var text = $('#ebPlaceholder').val();
             returnText = text;
             $('#ebDialogue_div').dialog("close");
         });
     }
 }(jQuery));
```

Html

```
$('#Id').DivPopUp();
```

Comment: maybe `return returnText`?

Comment: You need to give more detail about how this function fits into the plugin. Is it public? Is this code in the plugin or outside? What needs this value?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi This function is inside the Widget and i wana get it in the html page where the widget is binded

Comment: So this is a private function?

Comment: @Liam The problem is that the text will populate only when the dialogue is closed. How to know whether the dialogue is closed or not?

Comment: sorry getting my widgets and plugins mixed up!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30410/discussion-between-sreekesh-okky-and-liam)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JQuery, you can [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) a custom event.

An example according to your code:

```
_ebSaveDialogue: function () {
     //Saving Dialogue
     $('#ebDialogueClose').click(function () {
         var text = $('#ebPlaceholder').val();
         returnText = text;
         $('#ebDialogue_div').dialog("close");
         $('#ebDialogue_div').trigger('save_action', returnText);
     });
 }
```

Then, from any other point in your script, you set an [event listener](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for that event

```
$('#ebDialogue_div').on('save_action', function(event, returnText){
    alert(returnText);
});
```

Comment: I'm getting  jQuery.Event {type: "save_action", timeStamp: 1369225735726, jQuery19101334070337470621: true, isTrigger: true, namespace: ""… as alert

Comment: I made amistake :)
Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a [callback](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/how-to-use-the-widget-factory/)

so

```
$.widget('custom.DivPopUp', {

     //Call Constructor
     _create: function () {
         var returnText;
         this._ebDefineDiv();
     },

     _ebDefineDiv: function () {
         if ($("#ebDialogue_div").length == 0) {
             //Bringing Dialogue box
             $("body").append("<div id='ebDialogue_div' title='Expression Builder'></div>");
             var inDialogueDiv = "<div id='ebLeftPanel'></div><div id='ebRightPanel'></div>";
             inDialogueDiv += "<div id='ebSample_div' title='Sample'></div>";

             $('#ebDialogue_div').append(inDialogueDiv);

             this._ebCreateDialoge();
             this._ebSaveDialogue();
         }
     },
     _ebSaveDialogue: function () {
         //Saving Dialogue
         $('#ebDialogueClose').click(function () {
             var text = $('#ebPlaceholder').val();
             returnText = text;
             $('#ebDialogue_div').dialog("close");
             this._trigger( "complete", null, { value: 100 } );
         });
     }
 }(jQuery));
```

then

```
 $('#Id').DivPopUp({complete:function(event, data) {
     var returnText = data.value;
 }});
```

Comment: Im getting error Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLButtonElement> has no method '_trigger'